# Copy one column into another

Tags: powershell

I have two csv files and I want to merge them in the following way. Both files have the same number of rows. I want to replace the content of the i-th column from the first file by the content of the j-th column from second file.

Here is a short example. First file contains:

```
col0 col1 col2 col3
0 1 2 3
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5
```

Second file contains:

```
colA colB
4 5 
5 6
6 7
```

Let's say I want to copy `colB` into `col3`, so my first array should contain:

```
col0 col1 col2 col3
0 1 2 5
1 2 3 6
2 3 4 7
```

Let's call first table `table_1` and second table `table_2`.

```
$table_1 = Import-Csv -Delimiter " " -Path .\file1.csv
$table_2 = Import-Csv -Delimiter " " -Path .\file2.csv

# `$table_1.col3 = $table_2.colB` # -> error
`$table_2.colB.CopyTo($table_1.col3,0)` # -> no error, does nothing

$table_1| Export-Csv -Path .\file1.csv -Delimiter " " -Encoding Oem -NoTypeInformation
```

Is there any easy mean to copy content of one column into another column, other than doing an explicit index-based for-loop?

Comment: Please show at least the relevant part of the code you're using.

Comment: @Olaf Code added. Very simple code; I am stuck in the copy part. I would like to avoid copying element by element in a for loop.

Comment: What shall we believe,  your text `colB => col3` or your sample `colA=> Col3`? Otherwise as this are your requirements I don't see an alternative (using 3rd party Join-Object modules etc.). `for ($i=0;$i -lt $table_1.Count;$i++){$table_1[$i].col3=$table_2[$i].colB}` Isn't that complicated.

Comment: @LotPings Example corrected, sorry. I ended with what you propose; I wonder if there is another solution ... let's say more elegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to use the "Zip" method of .Net.

If you use it directly, it becomes hard to read like this,

```bsh
[Linq.Enumerable]::Zip($table_1, $table_2, [Func[Object, Object, Object]]{ param($t1, $t2) $t1.col3 = $t2.colB })
```

so you better wrap it with a function and use it.

```bsh
function zip ($obj1, $obj2, $rs) { [Linq.Enumerable]::Zip($obj1, $obj2, [Func[Object, Object, Object]]$rs) }

$table_1 = Import-Csv -Delimiter " " -Path .\file1.csv
$table_2 = Import-Csv -Delimiter " " -Path .\file2.csv

zip $table_1 $table_2 { param($t1, $t2) $t1.col3 = $t2.colB }

$table_1 | Export-Csv -Path .\file1.csv -Delimiter " " -Encoding Oem -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Like this solution. Not so easy, but avoid the classical for-loop.